# Cannot understand java wildcard

Tags: java, wildcard, covariance

I try to get foo() from my Main:

```
<T extends Main> T foo()
{
  return this; // "this" it is a instance of Main
}
```

And use it

```
Main m = new Main();
Main m2 = m.foo();
```

And I've got an error: "**Incompatible Types. Required T, found Main**" in method foo().
I know I can use this:

```
<T extends Main> T foo2(T a) {
  return a;
}
```

And use it:

```
Main m = new Main();
Main m3 = m.foo2(m);
```

And it works fine. But I cannot understand, why I cannot use first method? Because `this` is definitely instance extends of Main.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you define `<T extends Main> T foo();` in Type `Main` you cant just return `this`, because `T` might be a subtype of `Main`, which `Main` of course isn't. So if you have `MainSubType m = new Main().foo();` the Compiler wants to induce `T` as `MainSubType` but in face it is only of Type `Main`, so you have to parse it the hard way, which i cannot recommend here but that is how you go `<T extends Main> T foo(){return (T) this}`. If you do it like that you should indeed be able to compile the rest.

If it doesn't work with the (T)-cast in foo(), you will need to provide more context/code.

Answer (score 2):

As [user2504380 already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26257016/3182664): If this was possible you could silently "upcast" any `Main` to any subclass of `Main`.

However, you probably do not need this type parameter at all (at least, I can not imagine a case where it could make sense). If your class looks like this:

```
class Main {
    Main getIt() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

then you can create a subclass of `Main`, and, thanks to the [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) in Java, override the method to return the corresponding subtype of `Main`

```
class SubMain {

    // Overriding with a more specific return type:
    @Override
    SubMain getIt() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This means that the return type of the method is determined by the type of the reference that you are calling the method on:

```
Main main = new Main();
SubMain subMain = new SubMain();

Main m0 = main.getIt();
Main m1 = subMain.getIt();

// This does not work
//SubMain s0 = main.getIt();

// But this works: The instance IS a SubMain, and returns a SubMain:
SubMain s1 = subMain.getIt();
```

In the more complex scenarios that involve self-referential generic types, you might employ the [getThis trick](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I trying to understand java covariance.

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, in the case of

```
 <T extends Main>
```

the compiler cannot certainly determine the type of T. It can be Main or any sub class of Main. Because of this uncertainity the compiler won't allow to return this. If you cast the retrun type with T like

```
(T) this
```

or if there is a method parameter of type T, there is no uncertainity.